# Why my pipe ends only when i send a SIGINT

Tags: c, shell, pipe, zsh, waitpid

Basicaly, im writing a shell in C..
Im trying to implement the pipe feature, which is almost done:

```
 > ls | cat -e | wc | wc -l
 > 1
```

But i have a problem when trying to pipe a more slower/longer execution.

Indeed, when i try to pipe the result of 'cat /dev/urandom', it basicly waits...

```
> cat /dev/urandom | cat
>
```

But, when i send a SIGINT (with ctrl + c) to stop it, then it prints on STDOUT the resulted buffer..

[when i ctrl + c ,   cat /dev/urandom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VQL4.png)

So my question is: where should i be looking at to try fix this ?

PARTS OF MY PIPE EXECUTION:

```
    int         exec_apipe(t_me *me, t_node *curs, int is_last)
{
    int     pfd[2];
    int     pid;

    if (pipe(pfd) == -1 || !curs)
        return (0);
    if (!(curs->pid = fork()))
    {
        dup2(me->fd_in, 0);
        me->fd_in > 0 ? close(me->fd_in) : 0;
        if (!is_last)
            dup2(pfd[1], 1);
        else if (curs->parent->parent && curs->parent->parent->fd_out >= 0)
            dup2(curs->parent->parent->fd_out, 1);
        close(pfd[0]);
        exec_mpipe(me, curs);
        exit(-1);
    }
    else if (curs->pid > 0)
    {
        waitpid(curs->pid, &(curs->ret), WUNTRACED);
        handle_pid(me, curs->ret);
        close(pfd[1]);
        me->fd_in = pfd[0];
    }
    return (pid >= 0 ? 1 : -1);
}
```

I hope someone will understand what im saying, and maybe can help..
Thanks

Comment: Read all upvoted answers to: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to start *all* the programs in your pipeline before you wait for *any* of them to complete.

Your shell implementation is waiting for each pipeline element to finish before it starts the next one.  But `/dev/urandom` is an endless stream; `cat /dev/urandom` will run until killed.  So the second `cat` never gets started until you control-C the first one.

Comment: That solved it quite easily thanks to your very precise and explicit answer ! Thanks again :)